# Calling rest API within AngularJS & restangular

Tags: angularjs, rest, api, angular-services, angularjs-service

I have an API method that I need to call in my UI, and unsure the best way to do so. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Using restangular and angularJS. Should I create a service and then call the API Inside of it, and then reference that in my controller? Please let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain service layer, dao layer, view layer separately is the best practice.
You may look the [Design Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/design_pattern_overview.htm).

Answer (score 0):

The way I am doing is like this.
1 .First make an shared service first (shared.service.ts).

2. Create a method inside the service,there you call the rest api

```
  getData():Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(localhost:8000/api/data);
  }
```

or

```
  getData(){
    return this.http.get(localhost:8000/api/data);
  }
```

3. Inject the service into the component where you want to use

```
constructor (private sharedService:SharedService){}
```

4. Subscribe to the method that is defined in the service to the function where you want to call the api

```
  this.sharedService.getData().subscribe(response => {});
```

Comment: Can you explain the syntax in #2? The Observable<any> part

Comment: you can use like ````  getData():{
    return this.http.get(localhost:8000/api/data);
  } ````

Comment: The 'Observable<any>' is not compulsary. It is defining the return type. Since we are calling an http request , the request type will be an Observable. The '<any>' means the data type. Since the return type can be string or object or number. So we are defining as 'any'. The return type is not needed. Without that also it will work. I had edited the answer

Comment: Gotcha thanks. My team is using a “resource” file for other API calls, is that normal within restangular?

Comment: resource file (or) serivce file , both are meaning the same concept. The data needed for all the components are in those files. This concept is same for all the frameworks. The api calls will be writing in seperate files, so that all the other files can access on it through injection. Got it?